# Multiple Instances of bxslider inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, bxslider

I have created directive to load the bxslider because of the ng-repeat issue with it.
**Problem** : Multiple Instances of bxslider is generated because of ng-repeat over the directive.

When i am trying to wrap that div inside a another ng-repeat i am getting multiple instance of bxslider created one over the other.

JSFIDDLE:  http://jsfiddle.net/z27fJ/15/

APP.JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('startslider',function() {
return {
   restrict: 'A',
   replace: true,
   template: '<ul class="bxslider">' +
               '<li ng-repeat="picture in pictures">' +
                 '<img ng-src="{{picture.src}}" alt="" />' +
               '</li>' +
              '</ul>',
   link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      elm.ready(function() {    
           $("." + $(elm[0]).attr('class')).bxSlider({
                mode: 'fade',
                autoControls: true,
                slideWidth: 360,
                slideHeight:600
        });

      });
     }
   }; 
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.base = 'http://bxslider.com';
$scope.pictures = [
   {src: $scope.base + '/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg' },
   {src: $scope.base + '/images/730_100/tree_root.jpg' },
   {src: $scope.base + '/images/730_150/me_trees.jpg' }
 ];
});
```

HTML :

```
<div class="a" ng-repeat="t in [1,2,3]">
    <div startslider></div>
</div>
```

I have tried to search for similar questions and had no luck with that.

Any help will be really appreciated and Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are selecting your `bxSlider` in the link instance is incorrect. I assume selecting the `class` is generating multiple instances. Here is a way to make it work:

```
link: function(scope, elm, attrs)
{
  elm.ready(function()
  {
    $(elm).bxSlider({
      mode: 'fade',
      autoControls: true,
      slideWidth: 360,
      slideHeight:600
    });
  });
}
```